# RDP hangs to newly created windows 10 vm with "Securing remote connection..."

Tags: networking, windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-login

I've got a very strange problem since a couple of days. I run a cluster of vmware esxi hosts. These machines run vms for qa testing purposes. VMs are deployed from centrally generated templates for each OS (eg. windows-7,windows-10,windows-server-2016,centos-7,...). The machines are ready to use. The clones just need to get joined to the domain - if they are windows.

When I have cloned a windows-10 machine (lets name it 'qa-vm8') I can login with RDP to a local account just fine right after the clone. DNS/DHCP is prepared with the needed data ahead starting my 'qa-vm8'. So DHCP and DNS name resolution of 'qa-vm8' works direct and reverse. With just hostname and fqdn.

I login (via RDP) and change the windows NETBIOS hostname to 'qa-vm8' and then reboot. **From that point in time I can no longer RDP to that clone**. RDP hangs on

> "Securing remote connection..."

When I am also logged in with the same user on the VMWare Console that I try to rdp in I can see that windows 10 locks the screen so it basically accepts my login. RDP client hangs here until timeout (roughly a minute). I cannot find useful logs on client or server. I need to get RDP working using VMWare Console is no option in my case for endusers of these vms.

I suspect a name resolution problem as ahead of changing the hostname it works. But I can also be wrong. If I change the name back to the previous name it also hangs. BTW: The original hostname is "changeme" and unknown in the DNS.

This drives me nuts for 3 days now. Cloned windows-7 or server 2016/2019 machines work without trouble. I even created a brand new template from scratch with current windows 10 1903. The same as with my aged template that I always just updated from windows 10 1703. I also tried several clients on different machines.

I hope someone has already faced this problem and is able to help. I also tried connecting with ip address and qa-vm8 with and without domainname.

**BTW: I see this problem with any windows 10 version now. Not only 1903. Also with eg. 1809.**

Comment: Before you create the VMWare template, do you have the OS image stored with sysprep run. Are you deploying using any unattended files, etc.? It does seem like a DNS or WINS issue. I assume from admin elevated command prompt after the name change from the client machine you are having trouble connecting from you run `IPCONFIG /FLUSHDNS` and `nbtstat /RR` and maybe even `netsh int ip reset`? Using `nslookup` and `tracert` on a newly imaged VM before and after the change/problem and compare if anything is different.

Comment: Have you tried to see if you can RDP from a computer that has never RDP’d to that new VM, after the name change? Are you saving your credentials?

Comment: @Appleoddity: Thanks for your reply. No I am not saving credentials. I believe the authentication works (as I can see on the VMWare console window that it looks itself). Trouble happens after that when securing the connection/validating the certificate. And I also tried connecting from a machine which never had contact to this vm. Same result. Hangs on the same spot. :-(

Comment: Does it "hang" forever, or does it work after a timeout of about 20 seconds?

Comment: When clonig your VMs, may it be that you have duplicate MAC and/or IP addresses online?

Answer (score -1):

I'm having this exact same issue.  Have there been any updates?  Only happens on Windows 10.  I've tried it on Windows 7 machines and RDP works like a charm.

UPDATE: I finally solved this issue in my environment and thought I'd share what worked for me.  As it turns out the connection issue was being caused by a group policy.  In my case I have some USB device installation restrictions that apply to all authenticated user in my domain.  Specifically:

Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Device Installation -> Device Installation Restrictions -> Prevent installation of removable devices

&

Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Device Installation -> Device Installation Restrictions -> Allow installation of devices that match any of these device ID's

What I decided to do on this VM is to add the computer to the Delegation tab and then under Advanced set it to Deny in the Apply group policy permissions.  I then ran gpupdate.msc on the DC and then on the VM and voila I can log back in again.

There was an additional problem that apparently is part of a driver issue with version 1909 of Windows 10.  After connecting the first time successfully to the VM using RDP when I tried to reconnect a second time the VM the CPU was pegged at 100% and wouldn't let me reconnect.  The solution to this was to disable the WDDM driver in the group policy on the VM.  This can be done by setting the following GP to disabled.

Local Computer Policy
-> Computer Configuration
-> Administrative Templates
-> Windows Components
-> Remote Desktop Service
-> Remote Desktop Session Host
-> Remote Session Environment
-> Use WDDM graphics display driver for Remote Desktop Connections

I spent several days trying to troubleshoot this issue and it's not an issue with Windows 7 Professional.  I built a test VM to verify that it would accept a RDP connection and then disconnect/reconnect several times.  Hope this saves someone out there some time.